# How can I find the most used query from Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a Elasticsearch cluster running on AWS Elasticsearch instance. It is up running for a few months. I'd like to know the most used query requests over the last few months. Does Elasticsearch save all queries somewhere I can search? Or do I have to programmatically save the requests for analysis?

Comment: Are you ok with the raw query or do you want a normalized form (ordering in a query shouldn't make a difference, potentially even the searched value should be normalized away,...)?

Comment: what do you mean by `normalized` form? How is different about `normalized` with `raw query`? Ideally I am prefer raw query but I am fine if `normalized` query is readable.

Comment: Sorry, not normalized in the Elasticsearch sense but something like: You have a boolean query and two should clauses. Should the order of conditions make a difference or would you want to "normalize" it?

Comment: I don't want to normalise that. The raw query is fine for me

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, Elasticsearch doesn't by default save a record or frequency histogram of all queries. However, there's a way you could have it log all queries, and then ship the logs somewhere to be aggregated/searched for the top results (incidentally this is something you could use Elasticsearch for :D). Sadly, you'll only be able to track queries after you configure this, I doubt that you'll be able to find any record of your historical queries the last few months.

To do this, you'd take advantage of Elasticsearch's slow query log. The [default thresholds](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-slowlog.html#index-modules-slowlog) are designed to only log slow queries, but if you set those defaults to `0s` then Elasticsearch would log *any* query as a slow query, giving you a record of all queries. See that link above for detailed instructions how, you could set this for a whole cluster in your `yaml` configuration file like

```
index.search.slowlog.threshold.fetch.debug: 0s
```

or set it dynamically per-index with

```
PUT /<my-index-name>/_settings
{
    "index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.debug": "0s"
}
```

To be clear the log level you choose doesn't strictly matter, but utilizing `debug` for this would allow you to keep logging *actually* slow queries at the more dangerous levels like `info` and `warn`, which you might find useful.

I'm not familiar with how to configure an AWS elasticsearch cluster, but as the above are core Elasticsearch settings in all the versions I'm aware of there should be a way to do it.

Happy searching!